# Insert ComboBox programmatically inside the cell

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I want to insert object `curCombo` combo-box inside the active cell without defining widths and heights. In some of my test I worked this kind of principle, but I did not got that work as well

```
Set curCombo = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height)
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub comboBox1()
    Dim curCombo As Object

    '// Main challange is this set procedure here.
    Set curCombo = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, _
    Left:=Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Left, _
    Top:=Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Top, Width:=100, Height:=20)

    With curCombo
        .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 3
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "1", 1
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "2", 2
        .ControlFormat.AddItem "3", 3
        .Name = "myCombo" & ER.Row
        '.OnAction = "myCombo_Change" & ER.row
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What problem are you facing? and what is `ER.row`?

Comment: ER.Row is just a coordinates of a excel, which grows when I create new rows in my sheet. There is not any error message what I am facing. I just want to create a combo box which fits 100% in the excel cell.

Comment: Set curCombo = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(.Left, .Top, .Width, .Height) This worked with my previous tests somehow.

Comment: do you mean which ever cell you specify, it is should overlap that?

Comment: Yes Sir. Thant is the case.

Answer (score 3):

> do you mean which ever cell you specify, it is should overlap that? – Siddharth Rout 1 hour ago
>
> Yes Sir. Thant is the case. – AratioD 3 mins ago

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub comboBox1()
    Dim curCombo As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        '~~> Change this to the relevant cell where
        '~~> you want the combobox
        Set rng = .Range("B5")

        Set curCombo = .Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, _
                                              Left:=rng.Left, _
                                              Top:=rng.Top, _
                                              Width:=rng.Width, _
                                              Height:=rng.Height)

        With curCombo
            .ControlFormat.DropDownLines = 3
            .ControlFormat.AddItem "1", 1
            .ControlFormat.AddItem "2", 2
            .ControlFormat.AddItem "3", 3
            .Name = "myCombo" & ER.Row
            '.OnAction = "myCombo_Change" & ER.row
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thanks Mate! This piece of code helped me lot!

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I would recommend understanding how the code works :)